# How does Device Manager estimate ethernet cable length?

Tags: windows, networking, ethernet, cable

Device Manager (Network adapters / Intel(R) Ethernet Connection I219-V / Properties / Link speed / Diagnostics) estimates the length of ethernet cable between my PC and the router as 31 meters. How does it calculate this?

> Cable Length: Displays the approximate length of the cable between the adapter and its link partner. If the reported cable length is different from the actual cable length, this could indicate a break in the cable. Accuracy can vary by up to 9 meters. The cable length will only be displayed when the adapter is connected to a network operating at 1000 Mbps.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I didn't even know this was a thing... How can I find this on my PC? And I though it was 255m a few minutes ago, which would be WAY over the limits of Ethernet.

Comment: “How does Windows” – Not at all. What you’re looking at is a dialog provided by the NIC drivers.

Comment: @ColonelPanic I have no options like this on any of the three computers I checked.

Comment: I don't have it either, but it's neat. Do you know what brand of NIC you have?

Comment: @JasonClement The ethernet port is on an Asus Z170 motherboard, if that answers your question.

Comment: @ColonelPanic I can't believe I asked you for the brand when it says it right there in the first screenshot. I have the same model NIC and an ASUS board as well so I downloaded new drivers and now I have the diagnostics as well.

Comment: FWIW - my desktop has the same NIC as the OP and I ran the same test just right now - my computer is actually attached by a 3m Cat5e cable but the test result said I have a 17m cable which is more off than their disclaimer of "up to"  9m of accuracy. But I _am_ using a cheap Cat5e cable though... (and despite using a cheap cable, I'm able to fully saturate my 1Gbps link full-duplex - I don't think using an expensive cable is worth the ability to electrically measure its length...)

Answer (score 10):

I have found some clues in the manual
[AN-1508 DP83849 Cable Diagnostics (Rev. A) - Texas Instruments](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/snla085a/snla085a.pdf).
The device itself probably is not relevant to your setup, but the information
in the documents seems useful.

> The DP83849 provides a method of computing cable length based on
>   electrical  characteristics of the 100Mb Link. This essentially
>   provides an
>   **equivalent cable length rather than a measurement of the physical cable length**.
>
> 100MB cable length is a linear function of the Analog (AEQ) and
>   Digital (DEQ) equalization coefficient values in the linked state.
>
> ```
> if (AEQ == 0) Length = (A1 × DEQ) + B1
> if (AEQ == 1) Length = (A2 × DEQ) + B2
> and so on ...
> ```
>
> The algorithm for computing the electrical cable length is depicted
>   above. The constants {A1, A2, ... } & {B1, B2, ... } are determined by
>   statistical study of various typical case cables. The computation is
>   completely handled in hardware.

Another section of the manual throws more light on the measurement method:

> **TDR Cable Diagnostics**
>
> The PHYTER Dual implements a Time Domain Reflectometry (TDR) method of
>   cable length measurement and evaluation which can be used to evaluate
>   a connected twisted pair cable. The TDR implementation involves
>   sending a pulse out on either the Transmit or Receive conductor pair
>   and observing the results on either pair.
>
> The TDR cable diagnostics works best in certain conditions. For
>   example, an unterminated or open cable provides a good reflection for
>   measuring cable length, while a cable with an ideal termination at an
>   unpowered partner may provide no reflection at all. The TDR cable
>   diagnostics only works for twisted pair (copper) connections and is
>   not  supported over Fiber connections.

The final conclusion is that a pulse is sent on the Transmit or Receive
conductor pair and the results are observed. They are then searched in a table
derived using empirical tests and further improved by the firmware.
The result is not physically accurate, being only a statistical derivation.

Comment: Those are actually two different methods being described, one when the link is up and one when the link is down.